# Looking for a program that shows a real time spectrogram heatmap one at a time

Tags: voice-recording

Looking for a program that while recording the input of a microphone shows in real time the  spectrogram heatmap recording of the voice  like the spectrogram viewing option in audacity (as explained in the audacity manual in this [link](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html#:%7E:text=Spectrogram%20View%20From%20Audacity%20Development%20Manual%20Jump%20to%3A,energy%20in%20different%20frequency%20bands%20changes%20over%20time.))

Only I want the real time view of the spectrogram not to be a sliding spectrogram, meaning that the picture of the spectrogram will not move left and right while I record, but rather stay in place and change each frequencies values.

Comment: There are many plugins that can show real-time frequency spectrum. I don't know any that present it as a spectrogram, because it's not really all that useful compared to a simple line graph. e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7wLj.png

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are looking for.

Comment: (Later)  Okay I see there's been an edit.  I think I can follow you right up to the last 5 words.  You want a static spectrogram of a chunk of audio on a frequency basis?

Comment: Yes in real time froma microphone input

Comment: Hey Al. You can't have a spectrogram without the time domain. That's called a realtime Spectrum Analyser. It displays the frequency component over the last `n` range of time (I think `n` is usually a few ms).